# Filtering out ghost traffic from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

Recently I've been experiencing a large amount of (what I think is) ghost traffic.

I need help in creating a filter to exclude this traffic from my Google Analytics.
URL's are showing up that have other websites appended to them.

Almost all articles I've read mention including only relevant hostnames but this doesn't seem to apply to my situation.

[Here you can see the URL's with other random website addresses.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rleta.jpg)(overworlf.com/evite.com/shmoop.com and many others)

[Here is a screenshot of the hostnames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsv74.jpg) none of them are out of the ordinary. I suspect this ghost traffic is using my main domain looking at the huge amount of users.

Comment: Do you link to evite.com or overwolf.com at all on your site?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't link to those sites from my site. There are many other domains appended to the end of my URL's which I don't link to either. e.g. ibtimes.com, indiatvnews.com, sparknotes.com, ahaparenting.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted the same question at stackexchange, someone there was able to help me

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/118666/94264

"Almost all the analytics spammers insert data into your stats by pinging the GA tracker directly with fake data. They never visit your site and they usually just guess at the tracking id without knowing website host name associated with it. They won't send a host name, so it wouldn't appear in that report. See How to fight off Google Analytics referrer spammers?

That appears not be the case here. In this case these appear to be actual hits to your website. I tried one of those "top active pages" and it gives a 404 error. It looks like your 404 template has the GA tricking snippet installed on it. I don't think that is best practice. You could try taking the snippet off your 404 page. Then if you did get actual hits to such URLs, GA wouldn't count them as pages."

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when there are search and replace or advanced filters. Are there filters on your view that alter the Request URI?

EDITED AFTER IT WAS CONFIRMED THAT THERE WERE NO FILTERS:
Typically, tracking 404 pages is best practice (referring to your other post).

I don't believe that removing the tracking from that page will help anyway. Like the other poster mentioned, these hits are sent from bots most of the time and they never actually land on your site. The hit is sent directly to your property with an http call. It bypasses the site completely, so whether there is a 404 page or not, the hit will show up in GA.

Adding an exclusion filter to exclude traffic with a page path (not hostname) ending in ".com"

Comment: there are currently no filters on the view. This all started recently and I haven't changed anything on GA